# Vim - capture in between slashes?

Tags: vim, vi, yank, vim-registers

Is there a motion for capturing text in between `/` or `\`? I know there is motions for other symbols ---

`ci"` - Capture 'text' inside `"text"`

`vi(` - Visual capture `int var` inside `foo(int var)`

`di[` - Delete word `[word]` into `[]`

The only workaround I can find is by using [Vim Surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), and using it to change surrounding `\` into `"` (`cs\"`), and then working from there. However, not only is it that kind of tedious, but the plugin only supports backslashes, not forward.

Comment: I've probably edited my answer 100 times, but it currently works for any pattern (e.g. single characters, words, regular expressions, etc...) and works over multiple lines (_after moderate testing_).  Great question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could write your own text-object for this pretty easily.

```
onoremap <silent> i/ :<C-U>normal! T/vt/<CR> " inside /
onoremap <silent> a/ :<C-U>normal! F/vf/<CR> " around /
```

For it to work with visual mode :

```
xnoremap <silent> i/ :<C-U>normal! T/vt/<CR> " inside /
xnoremap <silent> a/ :<C-U>normal! F/vf/<CR> " around /
```

Similarly you could also do for `\`

Edit: Added info comments.

Comment: I think this answer definitely works the cleanest, though I'm having a little difficult understanding what it's doing. Nothing a little google-fu can't clear up. :)

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Just a follow up to this, I wanted the same thing for matching regexes. For the "around" flavor I really wanted to take it one step further to match the regex flags as well so I came up with this version

`xnoremap <silent> a/ :<C-U>normal! F/vf/h<CR>/\/[gim]*/e<CR>`

Seems to work so far!

Comment: One more update, to add "y" flag and also clearing the search hi-lighting after you're done:

`xnoremap <silent> a/ :<C-U>normal! F/vf/h<CR>/\/[gimy]*/e<CR>:<C-U>noh<CR>gv`

Answer (score 3):

**Here's one way to do it with a mapping:**

```
  nnoremap H mal??e+1<Enter>mb//<Enter>y`b`a
```

This mapping will yank everything between two occurrences of the last search pattern.

Place it in your `.vimrc` file to make it permanent.

**Usage for your question:**

- search for forward slash:  `/\/` *(note the backslash escape character)*
- position cursor between two slashes *(or on second slash)*
- press `H`

Everything between the last `/` and the next `/` will get yanked.

**Explanation:**

```
  nnoremap H mal??e+1<Enter>mb//<Enter>y`b`a

 - nnoremap H      map H in normal mode, ignoring other mappings    
 - ma              place a mark (named a) at the current cursor location
 - l               move the cursor one char to the right
 - ??e+1<Enter>    move to 1 character after END of prev occurrence of last search pattern
 - mb              place a mark (named b) at the current cursor location
 - //<Enter>       go to the beginning of the next occurrence of the last search pattern
 - y`b             yank to the location of the mark named x (note: ` = "back tick")
 - `a              go to the mark named `a`
```

**Example input:**

```
This is a *funky* string
```

- search for `*`
- position cursor between two asterisks *(or on 2nd asterisk)*
- press `H`

The word *funky* will be in the yank buffer.

### You can use words as delimeters!

**Example input:**

```
<br>
Capture all this text.
<br>
```

- search for `<br>`
- press `H` in normal mode when between `<br>`s *(or on 2nd `<br>`)*

### You can use regexes, too!

**Example input:**

```
<p>
Capture this paragraph.
</p>
```

- search for `<.\?p>` (*or* `<\/\{,1}p>` *to be more correct*)
- press H in normal mode when inside the paragraph *(or on closing `<p>` tag)*

### ...

A better approach might be to use a register to remember a delimiter, so you can use this mapping quickly and/or repeatedly.  In other words, you could store `/` or `\` or `<\?p>` in a register and use that to quickly capture text between your stored delimiter.

Comment: This is quite the extensive answer! It went well beyond the scope of what I was asking for, but I love how it can capture between any searchable expression. I will definitely be using this in the future. :)

Comment: @bark - Glad I could help!  I learned a bunch while writing it, so thanks for asking the question!

Comment: Is it possible to align mapping with existing Vim's convention?

ci/ - should change inside slashes
di, - should delete inside commas
va% - should visually select between and including %

Answer (score 2):

there is no built-in text object with `slash`. However there are plugins support customized text-object, like:
[targets](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim)

Comment: This may not have exactly answered my question, but thank you for the plugin link. I tried it out and it's kind of fun to play with.

Answer (score 2):

A recently proposed Vim patch adds a text object for arbitrary matched pairs:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vim_dev/pZxLAAXxk0M/discussion